A Gaussian process and a Rademacher proecss are sub-Gaussian
This is a question-and-answer just for me, but if you have alternate answers or comments, feel free to share them.
Let $(T,\rho)$ be a metric space and $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ be a stochastic process indexed on $T$. $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ is said to be $\rho$-sub-Gaussian if, for any $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ and $s,t\in T$, we have
$\displaystyle \begin{equation} \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda (X_s-X_t))] \leq \exp \left(\frac{\lambda^2 \rho(s,t)^2}{2}\right) \tag*{} \end{equation}$
In this problem, I would like to prove that the following stochastic processes are sub-Gaussian with respect to the metrics $\rho$ specified:
Gaussian process. Consider the metric space $T=\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\rho(s,t)=\|s-t\|_{2}$ (the usual Euclidean distance). For $Z \sim N(0,I_{d\times d})$, define $X_t = \langle Z,t\rangle $ (the inner product).
Rademacher process. Take any normed space $V$ with norm $\|\cdot \|$. For a set $\mathcal{X}$, consider a function $l:T\times \mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $T(\cdot, x):T\to \mathbb{R}$ is a $M(x)$-Lipschitz function for some function $M:X\to [0,\infty)$. Fix $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}\subset \mathcal{X}$ and take Rademacher variables $\epsilon_i$ which are iid uniform variables with range $\{-1,1\}$. Then, take the metric space $T=V$ and $\rho(s,t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}M(x_i)^2\|s-t\|^2$, and define the process $Z_t$ by $Z_t = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i l(t,x_i)$.

Gaussian Process. Let $Z=(Z_1,\cdots ,Z_d), t=(t_1,\cdots ,t_d), s=(s_1,\cdots, s_d)$. By definition, $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ are independent Gaussian variables (Jointly normal random variables that are uncorrelated are independent), so $X_t-X_s = \langle Z, t-s\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{d}Z_i (t_i-s_i)$ is again Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $\sum_{i=1}^{d}(t_i-s_i)^2 = \|t-s\|^2_{2} =\rho(s,t)^2$. Now, we note that the expectation $\mathbb{E}[{\exp}(\lambda(X_s-X_t))]$ is exactly equal to the moment generating function of $X_s-X_t$. It is well-known that the MGF of $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $M_{X}(\lambda)= \exp(\mu \lambda + \sigma^2 \lambda^2/2)$, so we have
$\mathbb{E}[{\exp}(\lambda(X_s-X_t))] = \exp(0\lambda +\rho(s,t)^2\lambda^2/2)=\exp(\rho(s,t)^2\lambda^2/2) \tag*{}$
which proves that $X_t$ is $\rho$-sub-Gaussian.
Rademacher Process. We have
$\begin{align}Z_t-Z_s = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i (l(t,x_i)-l(s,x_i)) \tag*{}\end{align}$
Similar to the previous problem, it is helpful to know the MGF of a Rademacher variable $\epsilon_i$. By definition,
$M_{\epsilon_i}(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda \epsilon_i}] = \frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda} = \cosh{\lambda} \tag*{}$
One more useful is that we have $\cosh{\lambda}\leq e^{\lambda^2/2}, \lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, which is easy to prove by considering $f(x) = x^2/2- \log{\cosh{x} }$ and proving by a derivative that the minimum of $f(x)$ is greater than or equal to 0$.
$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}[\exp\left(\lambda (Z_t-Z_s)\right) &= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\lambda\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i(l(t,x_i)-l(s,x_i))\right)\right] \\ &=\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}\exp\left(\lambda\epsilon_i(l(t,x_i)-l(s,x_i))\right)\right]\\ &=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\lambda\epsilon_i(l(t,x_i)-l(s,x_i))\right)\right]\cdots \textrm{Independence of }\epsilon_i \\ &\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2(l(t,x_i)-l(s,x_i))^2}{2}\right)\right]\cdots M_{\epsilon_i}(\lambda)\leq e^{\lambda^2/2} \\ &\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 M(x_i)^2\|s-t\|^2}{2}\right)\right]\cdots \textrm{Lipschitz assumption} \\ &= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}M(x_i)^2\|s-t\|^2}{2}\right)\right] \\ &=\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \rho(s,t)^2}{2}\right)\right]\end{align} 
\tag*{}$
Therefore, $Z_t$ is $\rho$-sub-Gaussian.
